# Why does this sql query provide error? Is there a better way to get what I am looking for?

Tags: mysql

I have this problem I have to solve. It has to be applied on the [chinook](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database) database. I am looking for combinations of song formats and genres that describe 50 or more songs.
They have to be in descending order based on the number of songs they describe.
So far I have come up with this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mediatype.Name, genre.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT * FROM mediatype JOIN track WHERE track.MediaTypeId = mediatype.MediaTypeId
    UNION
      SELECT * FROM genre JOIN track WHERE genre.GenreId = track.GenreId)
WHERE (mediatype.MediaTypeId, genre.GenreId) IN (
        SELECT track.MediaTypeId, track.GenreId
        FROM track GROUP BY track.MediaTypeId, track.GenreId 
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 50)
```

This, however provides an error that says

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (mediatype.MediaTypeId, genre.GenreId) IN...'`

1. Can anybody explain as to why this error pops up?
2. Can any body offer a better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `WHERE (mediatype.MediaTypeId, genre.GenreId) IN` <-- invalid, as the error message says. It could likely be replaced with a JOIN (on multiple columns). Anyway, use newlines to format the SQL / post.

Comment: You can't refer to the tables in the subqueries in the main query. And since you're using `UNION`, there aren't separate `mediatype.Name` and `genre.Name` columns.

Comment: You are using aggregate function without group by and you have not used alias with your derived table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be joining the `mediatype` and `genre` tables with the subquery that finds the combinations with at least 50 songs.

```
SELECT distinct m.Name AS format, g.name AS genre, mg.song_count
FROM (
    SELECT mediaTypeId, genreId, COUNT(*) AS song_count
    FROM track
    GROUP BY mediaTypeId, genreID
    HAVING song_count > 50
) AS mg
JOIN mediatype AS m ON m.mediaTypeId = mg.mediaTypeId
JOIN genre AS g ON g.genreId = mg.genreId
ORDER BY mg.song_count
```